# Qt - How to handle memory management for dialogs?

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I am running into the following issue:

- Users presses "Ctrl+N" which goes into function MainWindow::newAction()
- In MainWindow::newAction(), create a QDialog dlg(centralWidget()) and call dlg.exec()
- While dlg is open, users pressed "Ctrl+N" again

The result is that dlg never gets deleted (it will only get deleted once centralWidget() gets deleted).

The call stack is something like this:

```
MainWindow::newAction ()
...
MainWindow::newAction()
```

I am wondering how to handle this case. I want all of the local dialog variables from the first call to newAction() to be deleted by the time we go into the function newAction() again.

Comment: Try to make your dialog modal. The user will not be able to interact with your main window while the dialog is opened.

Answer (score 2):

You also can try something like this:

```
void MainWindow::newAction() {

    const auto dialog = new MyDialog(centralWidget());

    // When user will close the dialog it will clear itself from memory
    connect(dialog, &QDialog::finished, [dialog]() {
        dialog->deleteLater();
    });

    dialog->exec();
}
```

However, a good move would be to stop user from summoning more QDialogs than a single one, given that this one is a modal dialog(might be a good idea to keep this dialog pointer as a class member and check is it on screen already before calling `exec()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question right, you want one dialog to be opened and want to delete it before a new dialog request comes in?

If that's the case you can do following:

In `MainWindow.h` declare `QDialog *dlg = nullptr`

In your `MainWindow.cpp newAction()` function you can do following:

```
void newAction()
{
   if(dlg != nullptr)
   {
    dlg->close();
    dlg->deleteLater();
    //or
    //dlg->destroy(); // this will immediately free memory
   }
   dlg = new QDialog(centralWidget());
   ...
   //dlg->exec(); // This will automatically make QDialog modal.
   dlg->show(); // This will not make a QDialog modal. 
}
```

I hope this will help. Remember QDialogs when displayed with `exec()` they automatically behave as Modal window. `show()` will make it non-modal.

Comment: Using `delete` on a `QObject` is a bad idea (it could receive events after the deletion and the app will crash). Use `QObject::deleteLater()`, instead.

Comment: @RomhaKorev i agree with you.. i update my answer. thank you.